# lag when scrolling activity

Tags: java, android

In my applications main activity I have 19 images with `textview` under them in a `NestedScrollView`. Images size is about 25 KB and when I run application on LG G3 it has lag. What can I do? And caching images can help me?

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:src="@mipmap/brain" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/brain"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:src="@mipmap/dentist" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/dentist"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:src="@mipmap/dermatologist" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/dermatologist"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:src="@mipmap/digestive" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/digestive"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/ent"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/eye" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/eye"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:src="@mipmap/general" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/general"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                        android:src="@mipmap/gynecologist" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/gynecologist"
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                        android:src="@mipmap/heart" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/heart"
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                        android:src="@mipmap/infection" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/infection"
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                        android:src="@mipmap/inner" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/inner"
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                        android:src="@mipmap/kidney" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/kidney"
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is too complex. You have a RelativeLayout as root element (bad idea), which only has 1 child (a NestedScrollView) - your RelativeLayout is redundant and only causing unnecessary churn.

Start by removing the RelativeLayout and make your ScrollView the top layout. See if you can streamline the rest of the layout by using a TextView with drawableLeft instead of having a TextView and Imageview.

Instead of loading everything from the get go, you could consider using a RecyclerView and load only a subset of the images, and let your adapter load more as the user scrolls.

Comment: so if i remove relativelayout and use textview with drawableleft instead of a textview and imageview my problem will solved? i dont want to use recycler view

Comment: Your problem will be mitigated, but I don't expect to be solved. There are too many views to handle at the same time - everything is drawn because it's a LinearLayout as opposed to a RecyclerView or Listview, that only draws what is visible. And it should be drawableTop instead of drawableLeft if you want to display the image above the text.